# How to trace line by line by "gdb" C/C++ code?

Tags: ubuntu, c++, gdb, trace, codec

I have installed `gdb` and added `-g` option to my compilation command, but when I try `(gdb) s` or `(gdb) n` it says:

> The program is not being run.

It only works when I try `(gdb) r` and goes and stops where my program stops because of it's error(that I could see this without `gdb` in command line).

How should I trace line-by-line my code?

Comment: Add a breakpoint at some suitable location.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define a breakpoint, for example

```
break main
```

Then

```
run
```

and `gdb` will start your program and stop when it enters `main`.